# Eclipse keyboard command to add import statement

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a C# developer who is doing some Android development in Eclipse. One of my favorite keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> which brings up the SmartTag menu. This is incredibly useful for adding using statements on the fly.

As an example if I don't have an import statement for `System.Xml.Linq` but create a variable of type `XDocument` I can quickly add the appropriate using with the keyboard command.

Is there a similar keyboard command available in Eclipse?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm pretty sure he has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in mind, but I may be wrong.

Comment: This is even slicker than `CTRL + .` in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 25):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to "O"rganize Imports (like Crembo mentions).  Another neat trick is to go to Windows > Preferences, search for "Save Actions", and check "Organize Imports".  Now whenever you save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), Eclipse will automatically run the "organize imports" feature.  I find this quicker, since it's quicker for me to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (one-hand shortcut versus two-hand shortcut).

Comment: Is in Windows> Preferences> Java> Editors> Save actions

Answer (score 8):

**For Mac users the shortcut is:**

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

some useful Eclipse shortcuts, you need first one

**1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : Organize imports**

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> : Delete row
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> : Activate quick fix
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : Open declarations
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> : Line Comment
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> : Rename selected element
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> : Shortcut for shortcuts

if you need more refer [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is to start typing the type name, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to get the completions. Selecting the completion will complete the type name that you are typing and will also add the import statement. Short of that, there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, which will bring up quick fixes when you are over a piece of code with problem. There is typically a quick fix to import type.

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences->General->Key, you can have your bindings for shortcut key. This article: [Eclipse Short Cut Keys](http://tkramar.blogspot.com/2007/10/effective-eclipse-ii-shortcut-keys_16.html) lists some useful shortcuts.